# How to sample color from a palette at a fixed color distance

Tags: color

How can I sample from a gradient color scheme palette in segments of a fixed color distance? I.e, the next element appended to the generated list is a fixed distance from the most recently added color in the list. 
I have an initial color and would like to make regular samples from a color palette starting from this initial color.

Comment: Somewhat related to `ResourceFunction[“SampleColors”]`

Answer (score 1):

We can make a little helper function:

```
ClearAll[SampleGradientFixedColorDistance]
SampleGradientFixedColorDistance[cf_, n_, m_ : 250] := 
 Module[{dists, vals, colors, if, max, newvals},
  vals = N@Subdivide[m];
  colors = cf /@ vals;
  dists = BlockMap[Apply[ColorDistance], colors, 2, 1];
  dists = Prepend[Accumulate[dists], 0];
  max = Max[dists];
  if = Interpolation[Transpose[{dists, vals}]];
  newvals = if /@ Subdivide[0, max, n - 1];
  cf /@ newvals
  ]
```

Which we can then call:

```
colors = SampleGradientFixedColorDistance[ColorData["Rainbow"], 20]
```

Compare it with linear sampling of the color scheme:

```
linearcolors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[20 - 1]
```

Now we can compare the distances between successive colors:

```
ListPlot[{BlockMap[Apply[ColorDistance], colors, 2, 1], 
  BlockMap[Apply[ColorDistance], linearcolors, 2, 1]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Adjusted", "Linear"}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

It is not perfect, because color distances are not so nicely 'additive'. But it gives a reasonable improvement on the built-in.

Comment: Any way of modifying this to start at an arbitrary intial color? I realize some colors may not exist inside the palette but then I could just use FindMatchingColor.

Comment: I'm not sure if that makes 'sense': to which point in the scheme would you go? the first? If your first choice is 'too far' one can not guarantee that 'n' colors is possible…

Comment: So I have the color `#c4d167` but would like to take samples of colors that are evenly spaced beginning at `#c4d167`. I don't want any sort of "wrapping around" the gradient if that is what you are asking. But I think it shoulud be possible to take fixed sample segments to the right and to the left beginning at `#c4d167`.

Comment: So starting at #c4d167 then move to the first color of the gradient, then continue taking steps of the same size in the gradient?

Comment: Result would look like `colorset = {..., c - Δd, c, c +  Δd,...}` where `c = #c4d167` and `d` is the fixed color distance.